# Gedit: Saving has been disable by system administrator

Tags: gedit

I have a problem with *gedit*. If I start writing a new  file or edit an existing file the Save button and short cut to save is disabled. If I exit a modified document a dialog opens with the following text:

```
Changes to the document "<Name>" will be permanently lost. Saving has
been disabled by the system administrator.
```

The interesting part about this is that I can save the file from right clicking the document in the side panel.

I have tried removing gedit-related gconf from the terminal while logged out (`rm -rf .gconf/apps/gedit-2/`), but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the path to the directory you are working on? Have you done something similar to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1977434.html)? Also, read [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2126289&p=12560522#post12560522).

Comment: That's it. In Ubuntu-tweak there is a checkbox that disables Saving to disk. I though that was disabling hibernation and checked it. It might be a duplicate since other Gnome applications might behave the same.

Comment: If you wish you can add this as the answer and accept it, that way it can be of use to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a user wide setting in Gnome that Gnome applications can see, and if they want, obey.

**In Ubuntu-tweak:**

- Go to `Tweaks > Michellaneous`
- Uncheck `Disable save to disk`

**Without Ubuntu-tweak:**

- Press ALT+F2
- Enter `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-save-to-disk`
- Press `Return/Enter`